# _NSCFString tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]unrecognized selector - Need help debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting the following error message:

```
[__NSCFString tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdc7e610]
```

It happens after:

-Clicking a button that pushes to view2 where I have 5 text boxes. When you click in a box the keyboard pushes the view up so you can see what you're typing.

-After clicking "done" on the accessory keyboard view the screen returns to normal. If I then click on the screen after a brief delay (following the screen returning to norm.) the app crashes with the above error message.

NOTE: view2 is a normal viewcontroller. View 1 is as well but has a small table view on it.

I've been trying to figure it out but havent been successful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to show some code to see what's going on. It appears that an `NSString` somehow gets set as `UITableView`'s delegate, but this could happen because of memory corruption as well.

Comment: What code do you need to see? Let me know and I'll post it

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a zombie somewhere (an object that gets released while it's still in use. That can happen because a table view's delegate property is a weak link to the view controller.

If I had to guess I would guess that your view controller is being released, but your table view is not.

Run with the zombies instrument in instrument, or turn on zombies in the debug settings. (You should be able to find information/tutorials on both methods for finding zombies on the 'net.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan!  I ran my app with zombies enabled & the console log showed:  *** -[DateLogViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe018500
But im still not sure why it's pointing to the height of table view header that isnt related to the view that's crashing, any other thoughts?

Comment: I just ran instruments, which says "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'DateLogViewController' object (zombie) at address: 0x1097d0e0". This says the responsible library = UIKit; Caller = -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]; eventType = malloc

Comment: Your view controller is being deallocated for some reason, but the table view is not. How are you creating your DateLogViewController, and how are you moving from that to the other view controller and back?

Comment: See this link for a shot of the storyboard: http://d.pr/i/W4GX  The 1st VC (top 1 screen shot) is the root view c. & I have a side view controller menu. The root VC has a popoverView with a switch statement to select from 3 views. 1 of them = DateLogVC, which is a childVC.  The view with the crash is accessed from a diff. view controller.  Here's how I created the DateLogVC: http://d.pr/i/2ywI

Comment: I commented out the height for header & so far it's not crashing. Any idea why this is the cause of the crash?  I hope that's all that's needed to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

In this case adding the view as a subview has retained it, when you remove view controller, you still have a reference to the table view. but the view controller has been dealloc'd which is why the datasource (which is the view controller for UITableViewController) method is being sent to a deallocated instance.

I had a same problem. It was a problem with side menu. When view controller pop over, then first remove table view from the view that you are popping, then let menu controller to pop over that child controller.

Comment: Do you have any code examples or snippets to explain your fix?

Comment: var children = self.frontViewController.childViewControllers
        for (var i = 0; i < children.count; i++) {
            var child:UIViewController = children[i] as UIViewController 
            
\n
child.view.removeFromSuperview() //my fix
            child.removeFromParentViewController()
        }